# Дистрибутивы линукс

Tags: linux, дистрибутив

А собственно чем отличаются дистрибутивы Линукс? Только пакетными менеджерами и предустановленными программами? Ядро то одно и то же.
Edit:
То есть в чем отличие дистрибутивов на уровне ядра?

Comment: фоновыми рисунками еще

Comment: Ядро тоже бывает разное, собирают с разными опциями и патчат по-разному

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В целом линуксы между собой различаются слабо. Можно даже с какой то долей правдоподобности сказать что и между линуксом и bsd различий мало. Софт практически один и тот же, приёмы работы в целом одинаковы.

Но дьявол в мелочах.

1. Пакетный менеджер, метод распространения пакетов (прекомпилированные пакеты/исходный код)
2. Расположение конфигов и бинарников по умолчанию
3. Упор, например, на безопасность ([Qubes OS](https://www.qubes-os.org/intro/)) или размер ([Puppy linux](http://puppylinux.com/))
4. Используемая подсистема инициализации (sysinit, systemd итд)
5. Наличие мощной техподдержки ([RHEL](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/linux-platforms/enterprise-linux))
6. Гибкость настройки вплоть до исключения ненужных частей из компилируемых приложений ([Gentoo](https://www.gentoo.org/))

И так далее.

Реально же используется в production всего два-три дистрибутива и в последнее время всё больше отдаётся предпочтение Ubuntu LTS или Centos.

Answer (score 3):

Ядро, конечно одно, только разные сборки преследуют разные цели.

Какие-то больше заточены под десктоп, какие-то под сервера, какие-то под одноплатные компьютеры (тот же Raspberry Pi) и т.д.. Тот же Android по сути кастомизированный Linux.

Кроме того, очень многое зависит от, скажем так, идейной составляющей, которую закладывали авторы сборки.

Answer (score 3):

В различных дистрибутивах немного различные ядра (могут отличаться хедера)
Основное отличие - пакетный менеджер, dm, de, предустановленные пакеты распространяемые с дистрибутивом и стабильностью.
Каждый дистрибутив отличается по поддерживаемым версиям пакетов в репо.
В некоторых дистрибутивах есть заложенные модули преследующие коммерческий интерес.
Ну и разумеется различной по качеству и количеству информации - сообщество и поддержка.